# document pydantic.BaseSettings/BaseModel based classes with sphinx autoapi

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pydantic

I wrote a class like this:

```
class ComponentData(pydantic.BaseSetting):
    """dummy doc-string"""

    att1: str = pydantic.Field(default="def1")
    """dummy attribute doc-string"""

    att2: str = pydantic.Field(default="def2")
    """dummy attribute doc-string"""
```

the autoapi generated documentation with `sphinx-autoapi` (https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) looks like:

```
class ComponentData(
  __pydantic_self__,
  _env_file: Union[pathlib.Path, str, None] = env_file_sentinel,
  _env_file_encoding: Optional[str] = None,
  _secrets_dir: Union[pathlib.Path, str, None] = None,
  **values: Any
)
```

I would love to have it like this:

```
class ComponentData(
  __pydantic_self__,
  _env_file: Union[pathlib.Path, str, None] = env_file_sentinel,
  _env_file_encoding: Optional[str] = None,
  _secrets_dir: Union[pathlib.Path, str, None] = None,
  att1: str = "def1",
  att2: str = "def2"
)
```

.. basically, to have `**values` replaced by the actual list of supported attributes with their default values.

I know this is possible with `autodoc`, but how do I make it work with `autoapi`?

Comment: Are you referring to https://autoapi.readthedocs.io/?

Comment: no, I'm referring to `sphinx-autoapi`, thank you for pointing it out, I have updated my question.